# Page.PreviousPage.Master executes the master page instead of getting its value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, master-pages

Everytime i use the this.Page.PreviousPage and anythig inside this like thisPage.PreviousPage, it seems to executes the page instead of getting its values.

Im telling this because, any time i use it on the code, it redirects me to an error page i set on the Masterage.aspx.cs file that do so for pages that the user can access. Its only happening on these lines, because when i run the breakpoints, the programs redirect to error pages on those lines.

```
        if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null) //This checks if the previous page is not empty
        {
            GridView gridViewToExport = new GridView();
            string gridViewName = Request.QueryString["gridviewname"];

            //Check if the masterpage contentplaceholder exists
            if (this.Page.PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("CPH1") != null)
            {
                //If Exists then do this steps
                Control ContentPlaceHolder1 = this.Page.PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("CPH1");
                gridViewToExport = (GridView)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl(gridViewName);
            }
            else
            {
                //If is not existent, then continue with this.
                gridViewToExport = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl(gridViewName);
            }

            frmExportarDatos.EnableViewState = false;
            frmExportarDatos.Controls.Add(gridViewToExport);
        }
```

The error im getting from this is 'this.Page.PreviousPage' threw an exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException'   System.Web.UI.Page {System.Threading.ThreadAbortException}

Answer (score 0):

You simply add a check here

```
if(Page.PreviousPage.Master ==  null)
  //Some code.
else
  //Again some code.
```

Comment: 1) What asp.net version you are using here?

2) Have you use Server.Transfer to use  Page.PreviousPage here?

3) please show me you complete example here?

Comment: Im working with the Visual Studio SP1, .net Framewor 3.5.
I set the postbackurl on the button.